# WooCommerce Hook woocommerce_cancelled_order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Good Day,

This is my first time using stackoverflow, nice to meet you all.

Anywho, I'm writing a plugin for WooCommerce and I am automatically refunding an order when it is cancelled. My code works fine when I manually execute it in a separate file without the hook, however, with my hook it seems to not execute. I'm doing the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cancelled_order','change_status_to_refund', 10, 1);
function change_status_to_refund( $order_id ) {
wp_redirect( home_url() );
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

if( 'refunded' == $order->get_status() ) {
     return false;
 }


if(!($order->is_paid())) {
    return false;
}


$noRefundLimit = 24 * 60; //in minutes until booking
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
 'numberposts' => 1,
 'post_parent' => $order_id,
 'post_type'   => 'wc_booking', // WC orders post type
 'post_status' => 'paid, complete' // Only paid, completed bookings
 ) );
 $bookingId = current($customer_orders)->ID;

 $bookingStart = current(get_post_meta($bookingId, "_booking_start"));
 $time = (new DateTime($bookingStart, new 
 DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")))->getTimestamp();
 $nowTime = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
 $difference = round(($time - $nowTime)/60);//in minutes

 if($difference >= $noRefundLimit) {
     $refundPercentage = 1; //how much will we give back? fraction of 1.
     // Get Items
     $order_items   = $order->get_items();

     // Refund Amount
       $refund_amount = 0;
     // Prepare line items which we are refunding
     $line_items = array();

     if ( $order_items ) {
       foreach( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
        $refund_amount += $item->get_total();
       }
     }
     $refund_amount = ($refund_amount * $refundPercentage);
     $refund_reason = "Order Cancelled";
     $refund = wc_create_refund( array(
       'amount'         => $refund_amount,
       'reason'         => $refund_reason,
       'order_id'       => $order_id,
       'line_items'     => $line_items,
       'refund_payment' => true
       ));

       var_dump($refund);

       $order->update_status('wc-refunded', 'Order Cancelled And Completely 
Refunded');
       $order->save();
}
```

I have the first redirect line added for the sole purpose of testing if it redirects, which it doesn't! Any idea why this hook isn't firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your comment. It seems that the woocommerce_order_status_cancelled hook is good but the parameter is $order_id. After a tremendous amount of debugging I have the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'change_status_to_refund', 
21, 1 );
function change_status_to_refund( $order_id ) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );      

$noRefundLimit = 24 * 60; //in minutes until booking

global $wpdb;
$querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_parent = $order_id
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 $bookingId = current($pageposts)->ID;

 $bookingStart = current(get_post_meta($bookingId, "_booking_start"));
 $time = (new DateTime($bookingStart, new 
 DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")))->getTimestamp();
 $nowTime = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
 $difference = round(($time - $nowTime)/60);//in minutes

 if($difference >= $noRefundLimit) {
     $refundPercentage = 1; //how much will we give back? fraction of 1.
     // Get Items
     $order_items   = $order->get_items();

     // Refund Amount
       $refund_amount = 0;
     // Prepare line items which we are refunding
     $line_items = array();

     if ( $order_items ) {
       foreach( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
        $refund_amount += $item->get_total();
       }
     }
     $refund_amount = ($refund_amount * $refundPercentage);
     $refund_reason = "Order Cancelled";
     $refund = wc_create_refund( array(
       'amount'         => $refund_amount,
       'reason'         => $refund_reason,
       'order_id'       => $order_id,
       'line_items'     => $line_items,
       'refund_payment' => true
       ));

       $order->update_status('wc-refunded', 'Order Cancelled And Completely 
        Refunded');
     }
}
```

I had a few problems. $order->is_paid() returns false even though the order is paid (I think this is because the status changed from paid to cancelled/refunded) so my code wasn't even getting that far. Then get_posts wasn't working as expected. I was forced to use $wpdb. After that my code worked.

Comment: Yes I just found it. When you are cancelling/refunding the entire order `is_paid()` will return false anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use proper action `woocommerce_order_status_cancelled`.

Here is the example

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'change_status_to_refund', 10, 1 );

public function change_status_to_refund( $order_id ){
    //Do Something here
}
```